# Does event_bus consumer support to run Async. method?

Tags: vert.x, vertx-eventbus

I am new for Vert.x async programming. I have event_bus consumer, once it receives a message, then it needs to call a Async. method `async_method_to_access_database` to get database records from Database. `async_method_to_access_database` will return a Future. The code looks like following.

Here I have one questions:

Inside event_bus consumer, could it run a `Async`. method? I doubt whether consumer handler supports to run `Async`. method? In Vertx, I understand Vertilce contains event loop, it supports `Async`. method, I am not sure if `event_bus` consumer handler supports it?

```java
EventBus eb = vertx.eventBus();

MessageConsumer<String> consumer = eb.consumer("my_address");
consumer.handler(message -> {
  
    Future<List<DataRecord>> listFuture = async_method_to_access_database();

    listFuture.onSuccess(ar->{

        doSomething();

    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have async code in the handler. The important part to understand that you have two ways of sending messages on the eventbus: `request/publish`.

- With publish you just **fire-and-forget**
- And with `request` you will register a handler wich waits until the consumer answers the message by calling `message.reply()`.

In both cases your async code in the consumer will be executed, but when you use send, you have the option to have additional logic on the sender side, (e.g: repeat on error, validate response, etc)

```java
EventBus eb = vertx.eventBus();

// sender

eb.request("my_address","testmessage", h -> {
  if(h.succeeded()){
    System.out.println("successful access to db");
  }else{
    System.out.println(h.cause()); 
  }
});

// consumer

MessageConsumer<String> consumer = eb.consumer("my_address");
consumer.handler(message -> {
  
    Future<List<DataRecord>> listFuture = async_method_to_access_database();

    listFuture.onComplete(ar->{
        if (ar.succeeded()) {
            message.reply("updated elements successfully" + listFuture.size());
        }

        message.fail(1,"critical error") // will trigger error in sender
    });

});
```